# Loading a file in PPAPI

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi, ppapi

I have built a chrome extension which require data from a configuration file. I achieved it through NPAPI plugin but now I have to use PPAPI since Chrome is going to discontinue it Jan, 2014 onwards. Is it possible to load a file in PPAPI. If not, How to do this task through PPAPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons, you can't load general files from the disk. If you want to store some data on disk, you can use the PPAPI File I/O routines to read and write from files in the domain-isolated filesystem Chrome maintains (shared with the HTML5 filesystem APIs).

Sadly, this will be more complicated than the simple C++ file I/O routines you're probably used to. I believe there should be some examples of doing file I/O in the Native Client SDK.

Comment: Yes, I found this afterwards but now I have found a better and easy way to do this via native messaging.